# use fork in use-package

Tags: use-package

Because of [this issue](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/15541) I need to change the location of the sources of the `auctex-latexmk` package to use a fork. Unfortunately I can't find any way to specify the address of a fork in `use-package`. Do you know how I could work it out? It would be great to have something like:

```
(use-package auctex-latexmk
  :ensure t
  :location (recipe :fetcher github :repo "smile13241324/auctex-latexmk")
  :config
  (auctex-latexmk-setup)
  (setq auctex-latexmk-inherit-TeX-PDF-mode t))
```

as spacemacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality (also in Spacemacs) to install and use forks via the `:fetcher` keyword is provided by [Quelpa](https://github.com/quelpa/quelpa). Check out its documentation [here](https://github.com/quelpa/quelpa#overview) for the syntax to use.

Although, Quelpa works perfectly fine, another option is to use the [straight](https://github.com/radian-software/straight.el) package manager, or any of the other package managers listed [here](https://github.com/emacs-tw/awesome-emacs#package-manager).

`use-package` only helps with package configuration. Although use-package can help with installing system packages (i.e. from configured repo's), it does not provide a feature to help with installing forks.

Comment: Ok great, thanks a lot! Can I mix packages installed with different package managers?

Comment: I think usually yes... alos I think Quelpa is actually not really a package manager... just helps you installing packages (not removing them)